# matched dataframe more records than count

Tags: python-3.x

Im unable to figure out the issue, please help.

```html
            onprem_conn = pyodbc.connect(cfg.conn_us_pip['conn_db_us'])
            onprem_records = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT {0} FROM {1} with(nolock) where year={2} and month={3} and day={4}'''.format(cfg.Column_Names[TableName],TableName+"_odyssey",yr,mth,day), onprem_conn)
            onprem_records = onprem_records.astype(str)
            
              
             athena_rcd = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT {0}  FROM  emm_rep_prod.{1} where countrycode='US' and year='{2}' and month='{3}' and day='{4}' '''.format(cfg.Column_Names[TableName],TableName,yr,mth,day), athena_conn)
             athena_rcd = athena_rcd.astype(str)
             #print (athena_rcd)
             matched_records = pd.merge(onprem_records,athena_rcd, how='inner')
             mtcd_rcds_idx = len(matched_records.index)
             print (mtch_rcds_idx)
```

In the above case, im having mtcd_rcds_idx more than the count of records "onprem_records" and "athena_rcd".

Comment: i was able to analyze more into this, how to compare two dataframes without dropping duplicates ?

Comment: Any suggestions, would be of great help.